# Alternatives for developing an online application with video, webcam and mic features aside from flash?

Tags: flash, video, webcam

Is there any alternatives out there for developing an online application with video, webcam and mic features aside from flash? Just like tinychat.com and chatroulette.com

Thanks!
G

Comment: Maybe Java, maybe Silverlight... that'd be it though.  Unfortunately, I'm not versed in either, so I can't tell you definitively.

AFAIK, HTML5 still doesn't give you access to those portions of the client's machine. (webcam, mic)

Answer (score 2):

As of today?  Nothing is out there.

- **HTML5** is just not there yet.  Give it a year or three.  Maybe.
- **Java** has never done well in this space, and things are not getting better.
- **Silverlight** would be the strongest option I could think of, but support is far from as universal as Flash.

The term *"online application"* implies you want it browser based.  If so, then native clients are probably out of the question.